# ng-repeat affects the wrong place

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have written a custom directive named fRadioButton in AngularJS. As far as I know, ngRepeat directive affects the tag that it's used with. However in my case, ngRepeat behaves strangely. Here are the details:

My directive template:

```
<label>
        <input type="radio" value="fValue"/>
        {{fName}}
</label>
```

My directive's JavaScript file:

```
directivesModule.directive('fRadioButton', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
          fName: '@',
          fValue: '='
        },
        transclude: false,
        templateUrl: '/directives/f-radio-button.html'
    };
});
```

I use the directive from any page as follows:

```
<f-radio-button ng-repeat="period in myCtrl.periods track by $index" 
    f-name="period.name" f-value="{{$index}}""></f-radio-button>
```

According to the ngRepeat, I expect the genereated HTML to be in the following format:

```
<label></label>
<label></label>
<label></label>
<label></label>
```

However, it is generated as follows:

```
<label>
    <f-radio-button></f-radio-button>
    <f-radio-button></f-radio-button>
    <f-radio-button></f-radio-button>
    <f-radio-button></f-radio-button>
</label>
```

How can I directly duplicate the label tags with ngRepeat? I have tried it with `replace=false`, but it didn't work either.

I guess that `replace=true` runs before the `ng-repeat`. Is there a way to run `ng-repeat` before the `replace=true`?

Comment: This is not possible what you describing. The code you posted can't produce this HTML.

Comment: @dfsq wouldn't it be possible making the ngRepeat also a parameter and passing inside the directive? The expression inside ngRepeat is neither string, object or method. So I think I can't pass it either.

Comment: You can pass array inside directive. Check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array into your directive and render radio items inside:

```
.directive('fRadioButton', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      model: '=ngModel',
      options: '=',
      fName: '@',
      fValue: '@'
    },
    template: function(element, attrs) {
      return '<div> {{model}}' + 
        '<label ng-repeat="option in options">' +
        '  <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.model" ng-value="{{ option.' + attrs.fValue + ' }}" name="' + attrs.name + '" />' +
        '  {{option.' + attrs.fName + '}}' +
        '</label></div>'  

    } 
  };
});
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
<f-radio-button options="myCtrl.periods" ng-model="selected" f-name="name" f-value="id"></f-radio-button>
```

Here is a simple demo:

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Xcvt46ljV58513saq7BC?p=info

Answer (score 1):

`ng-repeat` repeats everything that is inside the element you attach it to

```
<div ng-repeat="period in myCtrl.periods track by $index">
    <f-radio-button f-name="period.name" f-value="{{$index}}"></f-radio-button>
</div>
```

EDIT
Alternatively

```
myApp.directive('fRadioButtons', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            periods: "="
        },
        template: '<label ng-repeat="period in periods"><input type="radio" f-name="{{period.name}}" value="{{$index}}"/>{{period.name}}</label>'
    };
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.periods = [{name: "foo"}, {name: "bar"}, {name: "foobar"}];
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/3010/